# How to solve I/O error dev loop0 and free space for the disk on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, apt, 16.04, login, sudo

I faced a problem with the space available on the disk and for dev loop0 it gave me 0 available space, so I deleted any old unused kernel as I googled that. My current used kernel was 4.4.0-36 so I deleted the only other version of kernel which was 4.4.0-31 as I searched.

I also used the following commands to solve that problem :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get clean
```

Although that the password is correct, I became stuck in the login screen when I rebooted my Ubuntu 16 later on. The screen was moved to a black screen with the following line for a moment and back again to the login screen:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error , dev loop0 , sector 22675464
```

I tried all the possible solutions available on the Internet, but unfortunately, when got the Terminal and typed `sudo` it gave that it does found in the `/user/bin`.

So I could not be able to solve this problem and I do not want to install Ubuntu again because I have an important work and files.

Could you give a full answer for this problem - and for the other problem which is the space problem - in a correct way?

Comment: This is helpful for me, try it...
http://askubuntu.com/questions/213512/buffer-i-o-error-on-device-fd0-logical-block-0-error

Comment: I had a related problem but not the same; for me I compiled exfatprogs and past that point things no longer worked well. My external USB devices were no longer recognizable. A very strange problem...